# Dropzone.js remove file link not working

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

This is my index page

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/dropzone.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dropzone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof Dropzone != 'undefined')
{
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone", {
        url: "parser.php",
        maxFileSize: 50,
        acceptedFiles: ".pdf",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        removedfile: function(file){
            var name = file.name;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'delete.php',
                data: "name="+name,
                dataType: 'html'
            });
            var _ref;
            return(_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
        }
    };
    )
}
</script>
```

and this is my delete.php page

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=newimg","root","");
    $sql =$con->prepare("DELETE FROM attempt010 WHERE name='$name'");
    $sql->execute();
    echo PDO:errorInfo;
}
?>
```

It's showing remove file link and it's working on the client side... it's deleting the image preview but it's not working on the server side.. it's not at all going to the delete page..

Comment: data: "id="+id -> where does that id come from? not declared in your code

Comment: changed the code...@juvian

Comment: Have you checked in dev console network tab if the request is being made?

Comment: yes I've checked it... it's showing an error mark and this...<a class="dz-remove" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove="">Remove file</a> Do I have to put the delete code in dropzone.js file???? Will it work then????

Comment: is removedFile being run? add a console log to it

Comment: no it's not running... Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: yes you have no closing ) for the new Dropzone( part

Comment: updated the code... but still it's not working and it's showin the same error on console log...

Comment: it´s not };) but });

Comment: I've changed it to  `});`  but after it the dropzone form stopped showing.. and in console this error is showing..Uncaught Error: Invalid dropzone element.

Comment: probably because the #myDropzone does not exist at that point, try adding console.log(document.getElementById('myDropzone'))

Comment: I've replaced the position of the code.. after the form elements.. now it's showing the form and all but while removing it's showing `(index):23 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Dropzone.removedfile ((index):23)
    at Dropzone.Emitter.emit (dropzone.js:58)
    at Dropzone.removeFile (dropzone.js:1104)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (dropzone.js:321)` and it's not removing the preview..

Comment: you are probably missing jquery library

Comment: added jquery lib.. thanks for pointing it out...now the preview is been removed but in the db records are not deleting....

Comment: well we are back to point 1, do you see network request on dev console? Is removedfile running?

Comment: Hey @juvian it's working... you helped a lot... thanks..  actually I wasn't checked it properly..  again thank a lot...

Comment: Well if the request is running then removedfile is too. So now it´s a problem with your server side

Comment: It worked @juvian... thanks

Comment: No problem, good luck